# What are this uniform and these medals?

Tags: identification, uniform, austria-hungary

Help identifying uniform from the 1900s?

Brought this uniform to America.

[image: Mustachio'd man with large shoulderboards and looped chains]

Comment: You'll need to include a photo or two and add some explanation of what you already know about the uniform and where it was from.

Comment: Is the original photo this blurry around the medals, or just the snapshot?

Comment: What do you mean by "These Medals"?  The uniformed man has a little cross pinned to his jacket, and the 2 large discs don't look like medals to me. His uniform looks like a US cavalry full dress uniform from the 1870s or a similar one.

Answer (score 2):

The only distinctive thing I could guess where the uniform came from is the United States according to the buckle. It looks like a Union Army NCO/Officer buckle.
It looks something like this:

[image: https://www.hanoverbrass.com/uploads/2/3/5/3/23531116/8574178_orig.jpg]

Comment: But the bright shiny helmet is/was not a US Army pattern. True, the US Army wore helmets in the late 1800's, but the helmets were black with brass national insignia.  Cords also not regular army.  If US, this is a militia uniform, not US Army.

Comment: And US Army officer's dress uniform of the period would double breasted, two rows of buttons, not the single shown.  Note this dashing fellow, numerous differences in the uniforms.  https://i1.wp.com/emergingcivilwar.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/custer-portrait.jpg